# Redirect URI in Gitlab for GitKraken

Tags: gitlab, gitkraken

I am using GitKraken Pro and a self-managed GitLab instance, which I want to connect to each other. GitLab wants me to add GitKraken as an application. One required value is **Redirect URI**, and I don't know what to enter there. This seems to be a callback, but to where?

Example screenshot:
[image]

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The [GitKraken/GItLab integration](https://support.gitkraken.com/integrations/gitlab/) involves

- OAuth authentication
- setting up an SSH key and registering it to GitLab

An URL would be used only [for webhooks](https://support.gitkraken.com/developers/webhooks/set-up/).

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution, I am in the applications section, and not in the section to create private tokens.